# Polarized capacitor in a crossover network

Tags: capacitor

A few years ago I bought replacement capacitors to recap my crossover network in my speakers.  I finally got around to starting my project and realize my 68 mfd replacement capacitors are polarized but my crossovers are not polarized,  I checked the replacement capacitor on my B&K Precision LCR/ESR and it is 68 mfd either way.  Since power supply voltages are not involved, should I be ok to proceed?

Comment: Depends on the capacitor type. What type is it? Some withstand no reverse voltage at all and get damaged, some withstand a few percent of the rated voltage in wrong polarity but might still become damaged during prolonged use. Are you sure a recap is even necessary?

Comment: The B&K won't put out anywhere near the voltage of your amplifier.   That's why you are measuring 68 each way.  Get the right thing.

Comment: I would say most amplifier put out “power supply voltages”. The amplifier attached to my pc has 28V and 50V rails

Answer (score 1):

Should you have more of the 68 μF electrolytics, you may wire four of those to get a 68 μF non-polarised capacitor.

[image]

Comment: Are there any lifetime concerns with this setup? I’ve heard of it a number of times but never tried it, and I’ve never seen it deployed in a piece of commercial hardware

Comment: @Bryan - Hi Brian, A non-polarized electrolytic capacitor, for a speaker crossover network, would be like an identical pair of them connected in series opposition.  It would be specifically designed with two anodes in the same package serving as the non-polarised electrodes. Polarized electrolytic capacitors were connected that way, in speaker cross-over networks, before the advent of non-polarized electrolytics.

Answer (score 0):

> *Since power supply voltages are not involved, should I be ok to
> proceed?*

No, you should get a non-polarized capacitor because they can properly deal with the AC voltages associated with a speaker cross-over network. Regular polarized capacitors will introduce significant distortion in your audio output on your speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You need to use a non-polarized cap. The polarized one will conduct DC when it's in its 'wrong' voltage, muddying up the sound and damaging the cap in the process.

If you can't get a non-polarized cap, your option is to use two polarized ones of *twice* the value, tied back-to-back. Two 140uF polarized in series would get you 70uF, so close enough.